# php-imagick failing to use inkscape for svg?

Tags: php, svg, imagick, inkscape

Our intranet webserver was recently upgraded and everything seems to be working fine except for one thing: converting svg images to png. The resulting image contains no colours and also lacks certain shapes and textblocks. Conversion using the commandline works ok.

One page creates an svg image based on information extracted from a database. My colleagues need to be able to include this image in MSOffice documents (Word / Powerpoint) and since MSOffice (at least as available to us) does not support pasting svg images, the server needs to convert these to something that can be imported, I chose .png. This worked ok in the old server, but does not in the new server.

Desired result:
[image: Desired result]
Result in new server:
[image: Current result]

The php code used is:

```
<?php
    $svginfo = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd\">\n".timeline($size, $proj_id, $doctype, $country_id, false);
    echo "Original SVG graph (cannot be copied or downloaded):\n<br />\n$svginfo\n<br />\n";

    $im = new Imagick();
    $im->setResolution(300,300);
    $im->readImageBlob($svginfo);
    $im->setImageResolution(300,300);
    $im->setImageFormat("png24");
    $im->setOption('png:compression-level',9);
//  echo "<pre>".print_r($im->getImageProperties("*"),true)."</pre>\n";
    echo "\n<br />Same graph converted into PNG (can be saved or copied):<br />\n<img src=\"data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode($im) . '"  /><br />';
    $im->clear();
    $im->destroy();
?>
```

I downloaded the generated .svg image and converted this on the commandline using the convert command and this produces the desired result.

```
convert -verbose ./test.svg test.png
'inkscape' '/tmp/magick-woO1Hsgz59Zy7flHR79-uPEM15KO0EE4' --export-filename='/tmp/magick-T6uesaqvJfn_oR6Lhk25OHP7a9ECdDW1.png' --export-dpi='96' --export-background='rgb(100%,100%,100%)' --export-background-opacity='0.99999999999900002212' > '/tmp/magick-eE3tyU77b7dFsLHW0lR0cbJU5UNCPTJ3' 2>&1
/tmp/magick-T6uesaqvJfn_oR6Lhk25OHP7a9ECdDW1.png PNG 1066x340 1066x340+0+0 8-bit sRGB 69180B 0.000u 0:00.007
./test.svg SVG 1066x340 1066x340+0+0 8-bit sRGB 69180B 0.000u 0:00.000
./test.svg=>test.png SVG 1066x340 1066x340+0+0 8-bit sRGB 69493B 0.030u 0:00.028
```

As can be seen in the response, convert on the commandline uses inkscape for parsing the svg file, which is the desired behaviour.

I think that the php-imagick part does not use inkscape to parse the svg information, but uses ImageMagick's internal renderer, which is described in several posts in several fora to be rather limited in possibilities for rendering svg.

The imagick section of the output of phpinfo() is:

| imagick module | enabled |
| --- | --- |
| imagick module version | 3.4.4 |
| imagick classes | Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator, ImagickKernel |
| Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version | ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25 https://imagemagick.org |
| Imagick using ImageMagick library version | ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25 https://imagemagick.org |
| ImageMagick release date | 2021-01-25 |
| ImageMagick number of supported formats: | 247 |
| ImageMagick supported formats | 3FR, 3G2, 3GP, AAI, AI, APNG, ART, ARW, AVI, AVIF, AVS, BGR, BGRA, BGRO, BIE, BMP, BMP2, BMP3, BRF, CAL, CALS, CANVAS, CAPTION, CIN, CIP, CLIP, CMYK, CMYKA, CR2, CR3, CRW, CUR, CUT, DATA, DCM, DCR, DCX, DDS, DFONT, DJVU, DNG, DOT, DPX, DXT1, DXT5, EPDF, EPI, EPS, EPS2, EPS3, EPSF, EPSI, EPT, EPT2, EPT3, ERF, EXR, FAX, FILE, FITS, FRACTAL, FTP, FTS, G3, G4, GIF, GIF87, GRADIENT, GRAY, GRAYA, GROUP4, GV, H, HALD, HDR, HEIC, HISTOGRAM, HRZ, HTM, HTML, HTTP, HTTPS, ICB, ICO, ICON, IIQ, INFO, INLINE, IPL, ISOBRL, ISOBRL6, J2C, J2K, JBG, JBIG, JNG, JNX, JP2, JPC, JPE, JPEG, JPG, JPM, JPS, JPT, JSON, K25, KDC, LABEL, M2V, M4V, MAC, MAGICK, MAP, MASK, MAT, MATTE, MEF, MIFF, MKV, MNG, MONO, MOV, MP4, MPC, MPG, MRW, MSL, MSVG, MTV, MVG, NEF, NRW, NULL, ORF, OTB, OTF, PAL, PALM, PAM, PANGO, PATTERN, PBM, PCD, PCDS, PCL, PCT, PCX, PDB, PDF, PDFA, PEF, PES, PFA, PFB, PFM, PGM, PGX, PICON, PICT, PIX, PJPEG, PLASMA, PNG, PNG00, PNG24, PNG32, PNG48, PNG64, PNG8, PNM, POCKETMOD, PPM, PREVIEW, PS, PS2, PS3, PSB, PSD, PTIF, PWP, RADIAL-GRADIENT, RAF, RAS, RAW, RGB, RGBA, RGBO, RGF, RLA, RLE, RMF, RW2, SCR, SCT, SFW, SGI, SHTML, SIX, SIXEL, SPARSE-COLOR, SR2, SRF, STEGANO, SUN, SVG, SVGZ, TEXT, TGA, THUMBNAIL, TIFF, TIFF64, TILE, TIM, TTC, TTF, TXT, UBRL, UBRL6, UIL, UYVY, VDA, VICAR, VID, VIDEO, VIFF, VIPS, VST, WBMP, WEBM, WEBP, WMF, WMV, WMZ, WPG, X, X3F, XBM, XC, XCF, XPM, XPS, XV, XWD, YCbCr, YCbCrA, YUV |

The inkscape binary is located in:

```
which inkscape
/usr/bin/inkscape
```

the PATH variable in phpinfo() reports (it apparently includes the path to the inkscape binary):

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

The installed versions are:

```
dpkg --list | grep 'inkscape'
ii  inkscape                          1.0.2-4                               amd64        vector-based drawing program

dpkg --list | grep 'magick'
ii  imagemagick                       8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3                  amd64        image manipulation programs -- binaries
ii  imagemagick-6-common              8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3                  all          image manipulation programs -- infrastructure
ii  imagemagick-6.q16                 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3                  amd64        image manipulation programs -- quantum depth Q16
ii  libimage-magick-perl              8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3                  all          Perl interface to the ImageMagick graphics routines
ii  libimage-magick-q16-perl          8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3                  amd64        Perl interface to the ImageMagick graphics routines -- Q16 version
ii  libmagick++-6.q16-8:amd64         8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3                  amd64        C++ interface to ImageMagick -- quantum depth Q16
ii  libmagickcore-6.q16-6:amd64       8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3                  amd64        low-level image manipulation library -- quantum depth Q16
ii  libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra:amd64 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3                  amd64        low-level image manipulation library - extra codecs (Q16)
ii  libmagickwand-6.q16-6:amd64       8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3                  amd64        image manipulation library -- quantum depth Q16
ii  php-imagick                       3.4.4+php8.0+3.4.4-2+deb11u2          amd64        Provides a wrapper to the ImageMagick library
```

As indicated above, I think that php-imagick is not using inkscape to parse the .svg file whereas the convert command does.

Could someone inform me how I can find out if php-imagick is actually using inkscape and if not, how to fix this.

Just for clarity:

1. I have SVG and need to convert it to PNG
2. The SVG is generated on the fly, it is not an existing file

I included the information I thought relevant, I assume more information is needed, but I do not know which. If you need more information to help out, just ask and I will add it.

Comment: if you convert a file to SVG using Inkscape, it will add a comment on the top of the SVG file: `Created with Inkscape`.

Comment: magick prefers librsvg over inkscape if available. There is one important restriction to that library: it does not understand stylesheets. Missing colors might be a hint in that direction. Also, you seem to be on a Debian system which has librsvg as a standard dependency.

Comment: It is correct that the server is a debian system. The issue is that it works as intended when initiated by the convert command on the commandline, but not when initiated in php via php-imagick. So I expect that there is either module missing or a (or multiple) configuration error in one of the packages involved in the chain starting in PHP and ending in ImageMagick.
If somebody immediately knows how to solve it, that would be great, but any hint that could help me find out what happens between php and imagemagick, and hopefully indicates at what level it goes wrong, is already something.

Comment: I know it is old thing, but did you find the reason? I have similar case on Heroku right now.

Comment: No I did not find a reason, I gave up on this for the time being and focussed to other pressing matters. If I will find time later, I might give it another try.